# How to delete a item from a custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to delete an item from a `listview` on selecting a check box in my `listview`. My custom `adapter` is as follows:

```
public class listadapter extends ArrayAdapter<list> {

private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
// private final boolean[] mCheckedState;
private final ArrayList<list> list;
private final Activity mcontext;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public listadapter(Activity context, ArrayList<list> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.listdata, list);
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text1;
    protected TextView text2;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = mcontext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listdata, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewLat);
        viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewLng);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxList);

        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                               boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
           // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.

                list.get(getPosition).setSelected(

                buttonView.isChecked()); 
           // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
          }
     });
     convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
     convertView.setTag(R.id.textViewLat, viewHolder.text1);
     convertView.setTag(R.id.textViewLng, viewHolder.text2);
     convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBoxList, viewHolder.checkbox);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.text1.setText(list.get(position).getLat());
    viewHolder.text2.setText(list.get(position).getLng());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Please guide as to what changes I need to make to delete an item in the `listview` on selecting a `checkbox`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking questions here, you need to describe the effort you've put in to solve your problem.

Comment: remove the item from your `list` and then in your java  activity  do this `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: @Egor I have seen other similar posts on stack overflow but it deletes the first item and then it gives an ArrayOutofBounds exceptiom

Comment: So why won't you add the code that you've used to the question description and not post a stack trace for the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: if (this.list.size() != 0) {
   CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxList);

   if (chk != null) {
    chk.setId(position);
    chk.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      int id = v.getId();
      list.remove(id);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    });
   }
  }

Comment: @Egor can you guide me now .. this is the code i use to delete

Comment: The first time i select a checkbox from the list it deletes successfully. When i select it again it the app closes

Comment: use chk.settag(position) and chk.gettag() for set and get position instead of setid and getid

Comment: Don't use holder for the checkbox. Remove the checkbox from the holder. And in the onCheckedChanged() method, delete the item from the list and call notifyDataSetChanged().